How do I calculate the total numbers of goals scored given the team key "arsenal". It currently returns 0
We want to be able to see how many goals a specific football team in the Premier League scored in total during the 2014/2015 season.
All the information you need is contained in this JSON file: https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hackajob-assets1.p.hackajob/challenges/football_session/football.json
This is what I have right now.
var https = require('https');

async function main() {
    return await Promise.all([
        getRequestPromise('https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/hackajob-assets1.p.hackajob/challenges/football_session/football.json')
    ]).then(results => {
        return results[0].rounds;
    });
}

function getRequestPromise(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let request = https.get(url, (response) => {
          if (response.statusCode < 200 || response.statusCode > 299) {
             reject(new Error('Failed to load page, status code: ' + response.statusCode));
           }

          let body = [];
          response.on('data', (chunk) => body.push(chunk));
          response.on('end', () => resolve(JSON.parse(body.join(''))));
        });

        request.on('error', (err) => reject(err));
    });
}

async function run(teamKey) {
    
const data = await main();

let score = 0;

  for(round of data){
      for(match of round.matches){
          if(match.team1.name == teamKey){
              score += match.score1;
          }else if(match.team2.name == teamKey){
              score += match.score2;
          }
      }
  }
  return score;
}

run('arsenal');

Output:
Expected:
71
Actual:
0

Seems like a perfect job for some step through debugging and some console.logging() at the right places to see if you got the data you expected at each step.

Unfortunately, I have been given a basic editor with its server therefore I can't log anything. It's quite frustrating.

So you have 0 debugging capabilities? Just write code and hope for the best? Can't you run this exact same script on your own machine?

The problem is you are passing the key of the team to the run() function and comparing it with the name of the team.
You should pass the name of the team like this run('Arsenal'); or change the run() function to work with the key like this
async function run(teamKey) {
  const data = await main();

  let score = 0;

  for (const round of data) {
    for (const match of round.matches) {
      if (match.team1.key === teamKey) {
        score += match.score1;
      } else if (match.team2.key === teamKey) {
        score += match.score2;
      }
    }
  }
  return score;
}

